# XSL - Remove Empty Tags and Tags with only zeros except one

Tags: xslt

I want to remove all empty tags of a xml (`<emptyTag></emptyTag>`) and i want to remove all tags with only zeros(`<zero>00000</zero>`) except the tag "apl" (`<apl></apl>`)

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl=http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform version="1.0">
  <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[ . = '']"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::apl) and . = 0 ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To remove empty tags works. Removing all tags with zero works, but it removes the tag `<apl>` also.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! `<apl></apl>` matches your template `*[.='']` is therefore suppressed by it. Add the `not(self::apl)` condition also to that template.

Comment: Sorry my mistake the value of apl is:
<apl>00000</apl>

After the first match - apl is still there, but after the second match apl is removed.

The hole path to apl is e.g. a->b->c->apl

Comment: Does your `<apl>` element perhaps have a default namespace? If so, you must include this in the test: `not(self::ns:apl)`.

Comment: Please provide a way to reproduce the problem by adding an example input. As you can see here, your code does NOT remove an element named `apl`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyfAiCu Perhaps the element is in a *namespace*? --- Do note that your code as posted here is missing quotes in `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" `.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thank you - that was the right clue :)

Comment: Note that `*[.='0']` will also match elements whose content is, for example `0.00` , or `    000    ` , or ` -0 `. A better test for "only zeros" is `*[translate(, '0', '') = '']` - which happens to match empty elements as well.